# Using (messy) data of another database inside my database with foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, data-transfer, sql-server-2017

I have a productive database with clean primary key / foreign key structures. It is pretty well designed and I'd like to keep it that way.

I now need to integrate data from another database. This database is from a different application and totally messy. No conventions, no clear foreign key structure, it's a real mess. However the data I need is managed by this other application and I need to make at least a daily update of the data.

The easiest solution I found is: creating my own table, have an import script running every day. Before importing the data => truncate my table.

This does not work however, because I would kill all my foreign key references with the truncation.

Another solution I have in mind is like the following:

Do a one time import and then update / delete / insert (new) data everyday.

This might get really tricky because of the missing primary key I might lose track of data records and insert them as new instead of updating the old dataset.

I guess I'm not the first one with a problem of this kind - but unfortunately I was not able to find any good advice with googling. That's why I wanted to make this post.

Is there any other useful approach which I currently don't see? Is there any other advice?